locally deployment with kubernetes using shared volume & replicas, nextJS app
I want to locally setup a kubernetes deployment for a nextjs app for testing purposes.
I want to create a basic deployment for my app image with 3 replicas. So I have this yaml file.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-deployment
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myappclient
          image: myapp-image:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
      restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000

So, this works fine but I need to have a shared volume for these replicas. After a lot of tries I had some errors especially with updating the ISR pages (e.g after updating content only one pod gets the changes etc). So now I have figure out that maybe I need to initialize an initContainer first to create the path where the data will be shared to pods. So I enchance the above (deployment part) file like this:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-deployment
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: shared-volume
          image: myapp-image:latest
          command: ["sh", "-c", "mkdir -p /usr/src/mydata"]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-data
              mountPath: /usr/src/mydata
      containers:
        - name: myappclient
          image: myapp-image:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: shared-data
              mountPath: /usr/src/mydata
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: shared-data
          emptyDir: {}

where
/usr/src/mydata 

is the path that I want & has created while building the image with Dockerfile.The case is that whatever I try I get the same errors:
kubectl logs <pod_name>:
Defaulted container "myappclient" out of: myappclient, shared-volume (init)
Error from server (BadRequest): container "myappclient" in pod "pod-name" is waiting to start: PodInitializing

kubectl describe pod <pod_name>:
Pulling image "myapp-image:latest"
  Warning  Failed     14m (x4 over 15m)   kubelet            Failed to pull image "myapp-image:latest": Error response from daemon: Get "http://localhost/v2/": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Failed     14m (x4 over 15m)   kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     14m (x6 over 15m)   kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff

(This running at windows machine using minikube for cluster setup and kubectl CLI)
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

What do you need a shared volume for?  How will the data be shared across multiple nodes (Kubernetes can't do this on its own), and how will your application react if multiple processes try to write the same file at the same time?  Can you restructure your application to use network-accessible storage, maybe a database, instead of local files here?

The purpose of the above is to have a locally environment based on kubernetes for my app. I want this so I can reproduce some production errors and test content updates and differencies between pods after updating content and stuff like that.
The case is I cannot setup a connection between replicas. I tried pvc, local volume, and now to use init container.
As I mentioned, with the first block of code my yaml deployment works good. I deploy my app and it has 3 replicas which serves data into my main app. The case is with ISR content as it seems only 1 pod updating with the content.

So, why Kubernetes?  If you're planning to run this in a multi-node environment, the shared volume probably won't work, and you need to redesign to avoid it.  If this will never be in a multi-node environment, plain Docker might be simpler to set up (you will still have concurrency-related issues with shared files though).

I already use kubernetes for my production build so I want a "local-reproduce" for this setup, so to be as close as possible.
So like in my real app I have 3 pod-replicas using a shared volume I need the same for my local setup, for the testing reasons I mention above
